# Activity Camera (in application Camera) is not responding

Tags: android

I've an application that opens activity camera with the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + image)));
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_ACTIVITY_OK);
```

The problem is that the camera application, after some "snapshots", returns the following error:

```
Activity Camera (in application Camera) is not responding.
```

After that, the camera application doesn't works anymore.
This problem happens only with Android 2.3 version

Could you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: What phone is this happening on?

Answer (score 0):

Snapshot"s"? As in more than one? That intent should only produce one shot, or the user can cancel the shot (producing no image). Are you calling the intent multiple times? If so, make sure the target image file (EXTRA_OUTPUT) is different each time. I probably can't help you without seeing more of your code or the error log.

BTW: Using the Camera app with Intents is now covered in the Android Developer documentation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intents

Comment: Hi Joe, in fact I call the intent multiple times. After receiving the image, it is deleted (new File (getFilePathPhoto ()).delete ()) - This works fine!. The problem occurs at the opening of the Camera Activity after running correctly sometimes.

Comment: When you say the "Camera Activity" is this your own code or a separate Camera  application provided on the phone?

Comment: Camera Activity is the same that Android Camera Application.

Comment: OK, so you run your application, it sends a few Camera intents, then you try to run the regular Camera application and sometimes you get a "not responding" message. Correct? We're still going to need more information to diagnose this: Attach the debugger, reproduce this problem and look at the LogCat logs when the problem occurs. If it's not clear what the problem is, post the log output in your question above.